# In OMNET++, trying to implement a very simple ned file, I get syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting NAME after gates:

Tags: omnet++

This is my simple ned file:

```
simple Txc1
{
   gates: (***)
    input: in;
    output: out;
}

network Tictoc1
{
  submodules:
    tic: Txc1;
    toc: Txc1;
    
  connections:
    tic.out --> { delay= 100 ms; } --> toc.in;
    tic.in <-- { delay= 100 ms; } <-- toc.out; 
}
```

I copied this exactly from a udemy course, to implement my first project. I get an error at the line marked with ***:

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting NAME

In the tutorial video the code does not have a "name" after gates and it works fine. Im using version 5.7 while they used version 5.6

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolons after `input` and `output` i.e.

```
gates:
  input in;
  output out;
```